# Find-by with multiple attribute in Ember.js Octane

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-octane

I have a route with RSVP that load several models (categories with items, treatments, prices) which return in JsON API Forrmat and want to show them in a table:

| Item Name | Treatment Name 1 | Treatment Name N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Category 1** |  |  |
| Item 1 in Cat 1 | Price item 1 in Cat 1 for Treatment 1 | Setup Price |
| Item 2 in Cat 1 | Setup Price | Price item 2 in Cat 1 for Treatment N |
| **Category 2** |  |  |
| Item 1 in Cat 2 | Price item 1 in Cat 2 for Treatment 1 | Price item 1 in Cat 2 for Treatment N |

*`Setup Price` only show if there isn't any price found, so the user can setup the price for the item in that treatment*

I already can iterate the categories, items and treatment; but still do not know how to configure to show the correct price.

How can I find the correct prices by 2 attributes? I tried using `find-by` helper in the template:

```
{{#let (find-by "item.id" item.id @model.prices) as |price|}}
  {{price.amount}}
{{/let}}
```

, but it seems it only support 1 attributes.

Well, if in SQL it would be something like:

```
select * from prices where item.id = [currentItemId] and treatment.id = [currentTreatmentId]
```

but I want it to search in the already loaded price model...

Any help ? thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [find-by from ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#find-by) it looks like you have the correct syntax. You may need to update this addon if it is installed or else investigate where `find-by` is coming from in your app as it isn't a default ember helpers. You can also solve this with a [helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/helper-functions/#toc_writing-a-helper-function). Invoked as:

```
{{#let (find-price-for-item item @model.prices) as |price|}}
  {{price.amount}}
{{/let}}
```

Which could look something like:

```
// app/helpers/find-price-for-item.js
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';

function findPriceForItem([item, prices]) {
  return prices.find(price => price.item.id === item.id);
}

export default helper(findPriceForItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for directing me with creating new helper, seems I really need to create a helper for that (I thought that I can chain the find-by helper that provided by ember composable helpers).

Just in time with your answer, I just need to chain `.find` or `.filterBy` for searching with multiple attributes.